# How to save Cucumber test results to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

I have some Cucumber tests that can be run from console with

```
rake cucumber
```

Is there a command line option to store test results to a text file?

Comment: Is this a Mac or Linux environment?  If so, why don't you just pipe the results to a file? `rake cucumber > outputfile`

Comment: @bigtunacan I am interested in Linux and Windows environments, but Linux is a primary OS in this case, thank you.

Comment: @bigtunacan But it will place all output (pretty long with all scenarios including steps) in selected file. I wanted to have the last part, actual results of testing, with list of failed scenarios and metrics.

Comment: That's true, but I don't believe cucumber supports what you are suggesting.  However you can use different formatters as described at https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/formatters or you could write your own custom formatter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either

- Run `cucumber` directly and use `-o`. From `cucumber --help`:

  ```
  -o, --out [FILE|DIR]
      Write output to a file/directory instead of STDOUT. This option
      applies to the previously specified --format, or the
      default format if no format is specified. Check the specific
      formatter's docs to see whether to pass a file or a dir.
  ```
- Run `rake` with `CUCUMBER_OPTS="-o whateverfile"`, i.e.

  ```
  CUCUMBER_OPTS="-o whateverfile" rake cucumber # assuming you're using a Bourne family shell
  ```

  or

  ```
  rake CUCUMBER_OPTS="-o whateverfile" cucumber
  ```
- Edit lib/tasks/cucumber.rake and add

  ```
  t.cucumber_ops = '-o whateverfile'
  ```

  to one or more of the `Cucumber::Rake::Task`s
- Or just redirect the output of the `cucumber` command yourself:

  ```
  cucumber > whateverfile
  ```

`-o` is a little different than redirecting: it always prints the "progress" output to the screen. If you don't specify a format it puts the default "pretty" format in the file. If you do (e.g. `cucumber -f html -o whateverfile`) it puts the format you specify in the file.

In case it matters, I'm using Ruby Cucumber 2.3.2.

Comment: That is a pretty good answer. Is there any difference between using -o and just piping results to a file? I suppose that proper formatter musе иу used to avoid getting all steps in that file. I installed cucumber_statistics [gem](https://github.com/alienfast/cucumber_statistics) and tried using it from command line. Got `cannot load such file -- cucumber_statistics/formatter
Error creating formatter: CucumberStatistics::Formatter (LoadError)`

Comment: There almost isn't, but there is a UI difference which I just added to my answer.