# Capturing and logging cucumber test results

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec, cucumber

I'm adding logging to a test suite. It uses Ruby, Cucumber and Rspec to run. I've already set up an env.rb to log each test and can capture Scenarios and Steps and drop them into the logger but I am at a loss how to grab the actual results.

Each test run will put something like

```
    1 scenario (1 passed)
    27 steps (27 passed)
    0m0.176s
```

into the console.

I know I can grab feature name, scenario name, tags and steps using the Before do |scenario| below but I cannot find anyway of accessing the results.

```
$logger.level = :info
$logger.add_appenders \
Logging.appenders.stdout,
Logging.appenders.file("logging/#{Time.now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y--%H:%M")}.log")
user = `id -un` #Mac specific, sorry windows users
user.delete!("\n")
$logger.debug "Test run by #{user} on #{Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}"

Before do |scenario|
  @feature_name = scenario.feature.name
  @scenario_name = scenario.name
  @scenario_tags = scenario.source_tag_names
  $logger.info "FEATURE: #{@feature_name}"
  $logger.info "SCENARIO: #{@scenario_name}"
  $step_index = 0
  $stop_count = scenario.test_steps.count
  @scenario = scenario
end

AfterStep do |step|
  if $step_index < $stop_count
    $logger.info "#{@scenario.test_steps[$step_index].text}\n"
  end
  $step_index += 2
end
```

It needs to output to a .log which is why I've so far avoided the html report builders.

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410895/how-to-save-cucumber-test-results-to-a-file/35413366#35413366) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Cucumber test results to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410895/how-to-save-cucumber-test-results-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that this does exactly what I needed

```
AfterConfiguration do |config|
    config.on_event :test_case_finished do |event|
        p event.result
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm attempting to achieve this exact same with Rspec rails

in the helper file I tried to call the config.on_event but it threw an error

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `on_event' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x0000563ce8230228>

have you documented or can you remember where or how configured logger ?